# Please help me with this events error with HttpProvider

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs, json-rpc, oracles

I have encountered this error while trying to put my oracle online. Please, help!

[image]

Comment: Hello! Could you please update your question to be more specific? Right now your question is more of a "debug me" and won't help others. Please read this and update your question appropriately: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Additionally, never leak your API keys even if you only use the key for testing. Your API key is visible in the screenshot you provided

Comment: And its better to copy and paste your code here, instead of posting screenshots ;)

Answer (score 1):

dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

This error tells you that Infura does not support `Web3.js` [subscription](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/ethereum/web3js-subscriptions#subscribe-newblockheaders) methods.

You can try a different provider; for example, Chainstack supports Goerli and `web3.js` subscriptions.

1. [Sign up with Chainstack](https://console.chainstack.com/user/account/create).
2. [Deploy a node](https://docs.chainstack.com/platform/join-a-public-network).
3. [View node access and credentials](https://docs.chainstack.com/platform/view-node-access-and-credentials).

Also, you will need to use a WebSocket endpoint for subscriptions as they are a continuous flow of data, so HTTP requests don't work.